# Google Analytics API blank screen when querying accounts?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics, google-api-php-client

I am novice to Google Analytics Api. I just started working on a small project where I want to pull data from the API and display it on each user’s Dashboard, using one single Google Analytics Account. I tried to follow the tutorial provided by google and made adjustments where required due to update to the library.

I am working on a codeigniter based platform and I was able to create a Google Client Object and also to make use of a refresh token which is saved in the database. I use the refresh token in order to have the data available on the dashboard without having to manually login every time.

The access token is there every time when I am logged in, and I can use it to set the client access token and create a Google Service Analytics object `($service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);).` I am printing the service and I can see the client id, client secret, etc and the access token being passed to it; but other like `Google_Service_Analytics_DataGa_Resource` Object are empty ( I do not know if they should be like that or not at this particular step ?).

When I am trying to request the user accounts

```
 $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();,
```

I get a blank screen and my view is not being rendered.

I could not find such a problem being encountered before, so I am a bit confused why is happening. I do not get any error messages or anything that might point me to the cause of it or the right direction.

Note: I did managed to make it work using the same credentials trough JavaScript, but in this case it is not what I am looking for. I was able to retrieve data, display data in charts,etc using JS. I am new to making posts, so if anything is required from my part in order for you to have a better idea of what is going on, please do let me know.

I would greatly appreciate it I could get any indication to why that might be happening, or anything that would put me on the right path.

Codeigniter controller Class as follows

```
 // Step 1 - Load PHP Client Libraries
 require_once APPPATH.'libraries/Google/Client.php';
 require_once APPPATH.'libraries/Google/Analytics.php';

 class GoogleTest extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){    
    $this->load->helper(array('url','form'));
    $this->load->model('googleapi_model'); //used to get the refresh token

    // Step 2 - Start a session to persist credentials
    session_start();

    // Step 3 - Create and configure a new client object
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("API Project");

    // Insert client id, api key, client secret, project scope and redirect uri
    $client->setDeveloperKey("***************");
    $client->setClientId('********************');
    $client->setClientSecret('******************');
    $client->setRedirectUri('****************');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));


    // Check if refresh token exists, it is used to login users automatically & it is being generated only once when you login the first time from the created 
    // google analytics app, this will take precedence to Step 4 or 6 below ; 
    if(count($this->googleapi_model->getGoogleRefreshToken()) > 0){
            $db_refresh_token = $this->googleapi_model->getGoogleRefreshToken();
            $client->refreshToken($db_refresh_token[0]->refreshtoken);
            $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        }else{
            if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
                $token = $client->getAccessToken();
                $authObj = json_decode($token);
                $refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
                if(isset($refreshToken) && $refreshToken != null){
                    $this->googleapi_model->insertGoogleRefreshToken($refreshToken);
                }
              }
        }

    //Step 4 - Handle authorization flow from the server
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
          $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
          $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
          $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
          header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 5 - Retrieve and use stored credentials
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
          $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    // Stept 6 - Either prompt the user to login or run the demo
    if(!$client->getAccessToken()){
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $this->data['auth'] = $authUrl;
    }else{ //Create analytics service object
        echo 'authenticated';
        $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
        //TILL HERE MY CODE WORKS FINE, NO ERRORS, VIEW BEING RENDERED
        $accounts = $analytics ->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();
        // $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($analytics);
        echo '</pre>';

    }

    $this->data['content'] = '/public/dashboard/google_test';
    $this->load->view('template/template', $this->data);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a PHP error? Do you check for error codes? What does the log say? As a side note, you should try to make your question more concise, as it's hard to read in its current form.

Comment: You should post the rest of your code that's not enough to help debug it.  BTW: $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();  (is faster) this might also help http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried debugging it already a couple of times, line by line to see what is going on; I also printed all the objects that I created. No errors encountered of any kind, just a blank screen, like Tibo suggested it might be an PHP error, but still it only happens if I try and make a call to the analytics created. I'm confused because it should be something straight forward and easy to do while following a tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're logged into the google account that API app is in. 
And that you have clicked 'connect'. 
Then run the script.

Also turn on error reporting (including notices)